# Loading data file with too many commas in Python

Tags: python, numpy, data-files

I am trying to collect some data from a .txt file into my python script. The problem is that when the data was collected, it could not collect data in one of the columns, which has given me more commas than normally. It looks like this:

```
0,0,,-2235
1,100,,-2209
2,200,,-2209
```

All I want is to load the data and remove the commas but when I try with numpy.loadtxt it gives me a value error. What do I do?

Comment: are the commas there because there are some values missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expression module to split

```
In[1]: import re
In[2]: re.split(',,|,', '0,0,,-2235 1,100,,-2209 2,200,,-2209')
Out[2]: ['0', '0', '-2235 1', '100', '-2209 2', '200', '-2209']
```

`',,|,'` means it firstly splits at `,,` and then in the result, it continues to split at `,`.

So if you want to get `-2235` and `1` instead of `-2235 1` you can use `',,|,| '` or `',,|,|\s'` to ease the eyes (`\s` means `space`).

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what you're trying to do.  I'd need to see a code example to see what you're trying to do really.  You could just replace the double comma with a single one

```
inputstr = "0,0,,-2235 1,100,,-2209 2,200,,-2209"
inputstr = inputstr.replace(",,",",")
```

Or, if you don't want to lose the position of the data in the string, maybe replace the double commas with a null value of sorts

```
inputstr = "0,0,,-2235 1,100,,-2209 2,200,,-2209"
inputstr = inputstr.replace(",,",",0,")
```

The key thing is that you don't want to corrupt the data, and introduce values that shouldn't be there.  It really is about what the data means and what you're trying to do.

Comment: Nice touch with the replace.

Comment: Well the I just need to put the data into an array with the command
inputfile = np.loadtxt("data.txt")
but when I do than, I get: ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 0,0,,-2235.
It seems like the format of the file is incorrect since the commas are so close together. What can I do to help that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is an option but you could pre-process it using `tr -s ',' file.txt`. This is a shell command so you'd have to do it either before calling python or using `system`. The latter might not be the best way since dragon2fly solved the issue using a python function.